# Update React component by dispatching action from non-react component

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to update the cart-button on a project when the user adds an item to the cart.

I have build parts of the site in React.js - like the cart, the cart button etc.

**configureStore.js:**

```
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
      const store = createStore(
        reducers,
        initialState
      return store
    }
```

**Action:**

```
export function updateCart(payload) {
    return {
        type: CART_UPDATE,
        payload: payload
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
export default function cart(state = {}, action) {

    switch (action.type) {

            case CART_UPDATE:

            const   cart = {
                        data: action.payload.cart,
                        errors: action.payload.errors,
                        isFetching: false
                    };

            return {
                ...state,
                ...cart
            };

    return state;
}
```

**CartButton.js**

```
... componnent etc.

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        cart: state.cart.data
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CartButton);
```

**Provider**

```
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
var store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render((<Provider store={store}><Cart showControls={true} /></Provider>), document.getElementById('react-cart'));
```

I'm dispatching an action that is supposed to update the cart quantity from a non-react component like this:

```
// imports 
import { dispatch } from 'redux';
import { updateCart } from '../../actions/cart_actions';
import configureStore from '../../store/configureStore'
var store = configureStore();
```

and then..

```
store.dispatch(updateCart(response));
```

The **action is dispatched** and the **state is updated**. The cart-button component is connected via. react-redux connect() function. But somehow it isn't updating the component with the new quantity.

When I dispatch an action from within my cart React component it works fine.

I might be missing something obvious. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you absolutely _sure_ that you're calling dispatch on the _same_ `store` that is passed to your `<Provider />` ?

Comment: As rossipedia said, did you instantiate only one store, or did you call `createStore` several times?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I am using the exact same store. I have updated with more detailed code snippets. I can't understand why it isn't updating. As I mention in the post; the quantity in CartButton.js is updating when I'm updating from the Cart.js-component.

Comment: I tried setting shouldComponentUpdate() { return true; } in my CartButton.js component but still no luck.

Comment: Uh, your code pretty much shows you're creating two stores. One in your "Provider" part, and one in the "imports..and then" part. This isn't too difficult to test, set a breakpoint in your `mapStateToProps` function and see if your new expected state is ever passed to your component.

Comment: It seems that you are right! I must have misunderstood the concept of the createStore. I thought that you would be able to require it from anywhere and it then would update the global state.

Is there a way for me to set the store variable globally, so I can use it in different non-react components?

Comment: I got it to work by simply importing the store from my root app.js-file. I don't know if that is best practice but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 20):

So what I ended up figuring out is that you shouldn't define your store in more than one place.

I simply imported the store constant from my root app.js-file like this:

import { store } from './app';

Comment: Thanks to @Sacho for clarifying