# Saving realtime listener in redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I need to trigger firestore realtime listener on login to listen to user profile data changes and cancel it before logout. To do that I need to save realtime listener in the store where I get stuck. I'm trying to do this in redux

```
export const cancelListener = (cancelListener) => {
return {
    type: actionTypes.CANCEL_LISTENER,
    cancelListener: cancelListener
}
}

export const uDataListener = (uid) => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(uDataStart())
    const dbRef = db.collection("user").doc(uid)
    const cancelSubscription = dbRef
        .onSnapshot(
            (doc) => {
                dispatch(uDataSuccess(doc.data()))
            }
            , ((error) => {
                dispatch(uDataFail(error.message))})
        );
    dispatch(cancelListener(cancelSubscription))
}
}
```

and on logout simply call it from the redux store

```
export const logout = (cancelListener) => {
cancelListener()
fire.auth().signOut()
return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT
}
}
```

However nothing is being saved in cancelListener therefore it can not be triggered. How do I accomplish this task? Please
Thanks

Comment: One way to achieve this is setting up a custom middleware to watch for the Redux actions you care about and then execute the firestore functionality you want accordingly. A nice simple example here: https://www.codementor.io/vkarpov/beginner-s-guide-to-redux-middleware-du107uyud

Comment: Hi Simran. I'm using redux-thunk as midleware.

Comment: I am not an expert in firebase, but what I can see you are calling `dispatch(uDataStart())` and in the end of that function `dispatch(cancelListener(cancelSubscription))`, summarizing it looks for me that you are doing `uDataStart` and right after that `cancelListener`.

Comment: Does your firebase listeners work without redux? Just set it up and see if they are called

Comment: cancelListener should save const cancelSubscription in reducer 

case (actionTypes.CANCEL_LISTENER):
            return {
                ...state,
                cancelListener: action.cancelListener
            }

However it saves value as null

Comment: firebase listener works just fine.. problem is that I need to cancel it at logout. to do that I need to save the constant in redux store where I get stuck. If I manage to save that then I could easily invoke it at logout

Comment: You should not store functions in redux store, some explonation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325195/should-i-store-function-references-in-redux-store

Comment: I knew this is gonna be a problem... Now question is how to invoke detaching listener in the redux. I I can not save it then I can not do it

Comment: @ptr.chov custom middleware solves this. Middlewares is an array in your store config, you have thunk there now, add to that array your own custom middleware that is listening for the  action you fire `CANCEL-LISTENER` or whatever. Great way to fire asynchronous functionality tied directly to the Redux actions you already have coded.

Comment: @Simran
Problem was that the function cannot be stored in redux state. I already tried to get it to reducer but as far as I'm looking into it reducer should not have any side effect so that won't work either. Actually I start to believe that there isn't a way to do it

Comment: I think you can simply store your cancelSubscription as a global object like window.cancelSub=cancelSubscription then you can use in logout with null checking. No need to mess up with redux flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have woken up in the middle of the night with other idea. I tried to add the method in the constant in action instead of saving the method in the redux state or reducer. I'm not sure if this is the best approach but it does the job. Now I just don't understand why I didn't try this approach in the first place. Here is the code which will need a bit of tweaks yet but it works

```
let cancelListener = null

export const logout = () => {
cancelListener()
fire.auth().signOut()
return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGOUT
}
}

export const auth = (email, password) => {
return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart())
    fire.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((u) => {
        dispatch(authSuccess(u.user))
        const dbRef = db.collection("user").doc(u.user.uid)
        cancelListener = dbRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
            dispatch(saveUserData(doc.data()))
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        dispatch(authFailed(error.message))
    });

}
}
```

Thank you very much for your help anyway. I really appreciate that

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick thought, in `uDataListener` call an action e.g. `START_LISTENER` and in reducer you can have:

```
    import { store } from './yourStore';

    let cancelListener, dbRef;
    function reducer(state, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
        case "START_LISTENER":
          dbRef = db.collection("user").doc(action.uid)
          cancelSubscription = dbRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
            store.dispatch( 
              yourAction(doc.data()); //Dispatch new action using store
            )
          })
          return state;
        case "STOP_LISTENER":
          cancelListener()
          return state;
        default:
          return state;
    }
```

`STOP_LISTENER` will be dispached when you are doing logout

Below you can see link how to dispatch from outside a component
[Update React component by dispatching action from non-react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457424/update-react-component-by-dispatching-action-from-non-react-component)

Comment: It looked promising but unfortunately this doesn't work too.. I think problem is that it take some time to get the data from onSnapshot so the state is updated with undefined values in start listener with error saying that

Comment: What does `db.collection("user").doc(uid)` return?

Comment: that is just a reference to the data location in firestore

Comment: I have added some update to my answer, nothing more comes to my mind

Comment: Thanks... I'm about to take a look at it... I'll be back with result

Comment: Unfortunately no luck there too. I'm getting exactly the same error there

"Given action "START_LISTENER", reducer "auth" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined."

I'm sure that the reason is onSnapshot is asynchronous and reducer doesn't like that. I'm sure it would work if I could find a way to wait for the snapshot until it get data and then update state

Comment: Do you have `default` case in `switch` which returns `state`? (added it to snippet in answer)

Comment: Yes I had that. I have just answer my question.. Silly me :) Thanks for your help